# Restriction of a singular metric with minimal singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, hermitian

Let $X $ be a smooth complex algebraic variety and $L $ a pseudo-effective line bundle on $X $, consider $h $ to be a singular Hermitian metric with minimal singularities on $L$ and $|A|$ be the linear system associated to an ample line bundle. Consider the locus of $|A |$ of sections $H $ such that $h|_H $ is a singular Hermitian metric with minimal singularities of $L|_H $.

Question: Should I expect this locus to be Zariski open?

What if $L=K_X $ and $h $ is the supercanonical metric?

Thanks in advance.